# Performance impact of a group by function call

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have the following query, which for simplicity sake I use the simple example format below:

```
SELECT 
  col1, col2, dbo.fun3(col3)
GROUP BY col1, col2, dbo.fun3(col3)
```

This took 30 seconds to run and returned 6000 records.
When I removed *dbo.func3(col3)* in both the **SELECT** and **GROUP BY** it sped up to only 5 seconds to return 6000 records.

So I guess my performance impact comes down to the following:

- dbo.func3() is slow and need further work to improve its performance
- The function call in the **GROUP BY** causes the slowness.

I wanted to isolate how slow is dbo.func3() is so I ran the following query without **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
```

versus

```
SELECT col1, col2, dbo.fun3(col3)
```

The first one returns around 900,000 records in 15 seconds.
The second one return 500,000 records in 15 seconds.

This prove I should improve my func3() function.  However, do you know of anything I can do in the group by part of the query to reduce the delays?

Is this function being called twice because I have it in the select and the group by portion of my query?

Comment: I had to post my suggestions as the answer due to the limitations of comment space, but feel free to ask further questions if I wasn't clear or about the results you get from those tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess my performance impact comes down to the following

Since your question is about performance I advise you to start using performance tools that you already have at your disposal to dig into this problem. This way your *guess* will be more precise or better yet: you won't have to guess at all.

[Display an Actual Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)

[SET STATISTICS TIME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[SET STATISTICS IO (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If after using these tools you are not able to figure out your answer, update your questions adding their result plus the function code and we'll try to help you further.

> However, do you know if anything I can do in the group by part of the
>   query to reduce the delays?

Without your actual code it's not possible to help very much.

> Is this function being called twice because I have it in the select
>   and the group by portion of my query?

It can be verified on the execuion plan.